# How to get eclipse to deploy dependent maven project to tomcat when also open?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

**The main question:**

Has anyone else run into issues deploying to tomcat when dependencies are also open in eclipse as sister projects?

**The Story:**

Eclipse with the Maven plugin is smart enough to adjust the deployment assembly part of the configuration automatically, meaning that if you have a dependency in your web project and it is also open in eclipse, then you will get (among others) two entries in the deployment assembly listing:

- One referencing the sister project and which outputs to `WEB-INF/lib/sister-project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
- And a second one referencing the usual Maven Dependencies entry that outputs to `WEB-INF/lib/`

This however does not seem to work :/
ie. the jar from the sister project is not constructed/deployed out to the tomcat server, which of course results in the good old `ClassNotFoundException`.

Now, in the past, I swear this worked, but for some reason it doesn't in the ?current? version of eclipse (I'm running `Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)`).

**Current workaround:**

Instead you run a quick maven-install on the sister project, and then close the project.  This makes eclipse realize it needs to pull in this dependency as a regular maven dependency (from your local .m2), and since you just installed it there it has the most up to date version of your code.

The deployment assembly automatically updates, and just has:

- The entry referencing the usual Maven Dependencies entry that outputs to `WEB-INF/lib/`

(The project reference is removed, as expected).

In this case, it goes ahead and finds the jar as part of the other maven dependencies and happily deploys it out to the server.

---

One theory I have is that it is wrong to want the output of the sister project (when it is open) to be a .jar, and instead should/could be routing it out to `WEB-INF/classes/` along with the current projects class files.

Another theory, similar vein, would be that something is odd in the sister project where eclipse is not able to get a .jar file from it to output.

---

Hopefully someone else has come across this same situation before. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this works as expected in eclipse 2018-12 and also worked in 2018-09: The dependency when opened in workspace is built to a `.jar` and deployed into `WEB-INF/lib`.

There is a setting for this you should check for each participating project:

`Project properties (Alt+Return) -> Maven -> [x] Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects`,

When things are odd it also frequently helps to do a Maven project update:

`Open the project context menu -> Maven -> Update Project -> All`.

Comment: hehe, yes, I have done these two things before.
In terms of 1, if that behaviour wasn't checked, I'd expect it to not be updating the deployment assembly/changing the build path as I open/close the other project.
In terms of 2, alt-f5 is my friend and has helped me resolve many an issue in the past.

Comment: Quick question, do you see the .jar show up automatically in the /target directory of the sister-project as well? (trying to trace back to see if I can figure out if it is an issue with it being created vs being copied). (in the past I have had issues with file-locking sometimes preventing things from being happy, so figured I'd check)

Comment: @CasualT the jar is only present in `./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/WEBAPPNAME/WEB-INF/lib/ARTIFACTID-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` - I also see it in the WebApp project explorer as a subnode of `Java Resources / Maven Dependencies / ARTIFACTID` but in opposite to other third parti dependencies there is no `.jar` suffix and the icon is a Eclipse Project icon instead of a jar icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The opened child project jar was in the WEB-INF/lib folder but somehow not seen by Tomcat.

I have resolved the issue by enabling "Serve modules without publishing" in the Tomcat configuration "Overview" page.

Comment: Highlight or differentiate keywords